# Remove a node at the tail of a linked list C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, tail

I wrote code to remove the node at the tail of a linked list. The code works properly in different testcases, but I think I made my code a bit cumbersome. However, I don't see what I can do differently?

```
node_t *remove_t (node_t *l){
if (l==NULL){
    return l;
}
else {
    node_t *curr=l;
    node_t *ret=l;
    if (curr->next==NULL){
        l=NULL;
        return l;
    }
    else {
        while (curr->next->next!=NULL){
            curr=curr->next;
        }
        curr->next=NULL;
        free(curr->next);
        return ret;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a better question for [codereview.se].

Comment: `curr->next=NULL;` overwrites the pointer at `curr->next` (creating a memory leak), then calling `free(curr->next);` has no effect. Equivalent to `free (NULL);`. Always use `valgrind` (or a similar memory use/error checking program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can change the logic much - as your approach of 3 different cases (empty list, list with 1 item, and list with >1 items) is reasonable. You can format the code for easier reading: Something like:

```
node_t *remove_t (node_t *l){
    // case 1: Empty list
    if (l==NULL){
        return l;
    } ;

    // case 2: List with one item. Return empty list.
    node_t *curr=l;
    if (curr->next==NULL){
        // Remember to free this element.
        free(curr) ;
        l=NULL;
        return l;
    } ;

    // case 3: list > one item
    // Move curr to last item
    while (curr->next->next!=NULL){
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    // Note order of free/null setting.
    free(curr->next);
    curr->next=NULL;

    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much, much easier if you keep a *pointer-to-pointer* to node, then iterate to the end of list and simply free the last pointer and set it `NULL`, e.g.

```
/** delete last node */
void del_last_node (node_t **l)
{
    node_t **ppn = l;       /* pointer to pointer */
    node_t *pn = *l;        /* pointer to node */

    for (; pn->next; ppn = &pn->next, pn = pn->next) { } /* iterate to last */

    free (*ppn);           /* free node */
    *ppn = NULL;           /* set pointer NULL */
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, need to handle the empty list case (*l == null).

Comment: Yes that can be added with `if (!*l) return;`, but I generally ensure a list is not `NULL` before calling functions that operate on it. But to protect the user from themselves completely, it isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't seem to free the tail node.

```
curr->next=NULL;
free(curr->next);
```

You won't be able to free curr->next if you already make it NULL.

My implementation:

```
void remove_tail(node_t *l) {
    if (l == NULL) return;
    if (l->next == NULL) {
        free(l);
        l = NULL;
        return;
    }
    node_t *prev = l;
    node_t *curr = l->next;
    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    prev->next = NULL;
    free(curr);
}
```